# Deserialize JSON object containing array to C# object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

This is my JSON string:

```
{"type":"motor","ids":["1","2","5","7","8","10"]}
```

And this is the object I want to generate from it:

```
public class ElementArray {
    public ElementType type;
    public String[] ids;

    public ElementArray() {
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that? I googled about Json.NET, but they only explain [how to deserialize an array](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm) but not how to deserialize an object containing an array as a field (see my class above).

What I tried is

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
ElementArray elements = jss.Deserialize<ElementArray>(strJson);
```

but when I debug the code, the field `ids` contains `null`.

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. This code does not compile, and if you fix it so it does, it will run just fine. You're also linking to the Newtonsoft.Json documentation, while you are using .NET's JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: I am using JavaScriptSerializer because that is what I was using all the time until I ran into this issue. And I linked NewtonSoft.JSON documentation because I googled about it but only found the example I linked to which, in my opinion, doesn't fit properly

Comment: There is nothing special about an object having a collection member. I copied this JSON and this code and it runs just fine. Again, read and create a [mcve]. In simplifying your example you left something out that is crucial to reproducing the issue you encounter.

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact json you're deserializing? I tried your code in LINQPad with the exact example you gave and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Actually, now it worked for me after I rewrote the whole thing... But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO simplest way to deal with json is using newtonsoft.json library

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

And here is example how to deserialize object:

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: I think that was what I was talking about. But it worked for me with `JavaScriptSerializer` as well.

Comment: How does this answer get three upvotes and accepted? The OP posted a non-reproducible problem using JavaScriptSerializer. This answer incorrectly advises to use Newtonsoft.Json. Yes, the latter has a nicer API and more functionality, but it **does not solve the OP's problem, as there was none**. _"Use library Y"_ is never the answer to _"How can I make this code using library X work?"_.